# Using MySQL triggers to create database on insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

Can I use a trigger in MySQL to create a new database when a value is inserted into another database.

Answer (score 5):

There is definitely a design problem in why you want to do this. (Create a database in trigger). As it turns out this is not allowed. [This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) is a list of what all is allowed to be placed in a trigger.